# Return type of array access

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, reference

The below compiles:

```
int main() {
    int v[] = {0,1,2};
    int a = v[0];
    int& b = v[0];
}
```

How is it possible that array access (bracket notation) returns an int type in one line, but an int reference in another line? What exactly is the return type of array bracket access, then?

I am new to c++, pardon my ignorance.

Comment: Raw array indexing returns a reference in all cases. Or in standardese, it's an lvalue expression.

Comment: Indeed. `int a = v[0];` is similar to `int c = b;`. You're asking for a copy of the referenced value to be made.

Answer (score 1):

`b` is a reference to `v[0]`, so their address is the same, that means **`b` is `v[0]`**.  But `a` is an another variable, so `a` is just equal to `v[0]`, but **`a` is not `v[0]`**, their address is not the same.

**For your question**, if you have some experience in c language, you can easily write expressions like 
`if(&v[0]==&b) 
     printf("b is a reference to int");`

or

`if(&v[0]!=&a) 
     printf("a is an int");`

to judge that.

Answer (score 0):

`b` is an int reference. So, it is an alias to `v[0]` and thus is an int. `a`, on the other hand, gets a copy of the value of `v[0]`. So, if `v[0]` changes, `a` doesn't get the new value but `b` gets the new value.

Suppose after your code, you do something like:

```
v[0] = 7;
cout << "a: " << a << "\n";
cout << "b: " << b << "\n";
```

The output will be:

```
a: 0
b: 7
```